# How to use variable from razor view in controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have variable in my layout.cshtml and I would like to use it in my controller. Is this possible and how to accomplish this?

Comment: The controller code is running on the server side. A view content related to the client side. Therefore you can't use variable from your `layout.cshtml` in the controller, but you can pass it value from the view to the controller.

Comment: So, I have "a class" of type button in my layout.cshtml. How to pass its value of the last pressed button in navbar and to use it in the controller?

Comment: You can use `tag-helper` like `asp-controller=""` and `asp-action=""` to pass the data to  controller.

Answer (score 0):

Although Model Binding is one way in Razor Views but using the hack on `TempData`, you accomplish this.

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    SomeModel model = ...
    TempData["foo"] = model;
    return RedirectToAction("Bar");
}

public ActionResult Bar()
{
    var model = TempData["foo"] as SomeModel;
    ...
}
```